# click handler leaflet on Vue 3 composition API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, leaflet, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

hello i want to ask about leaflet in vue 3 compostion API, how to get value latlng when i click on the map. i have tried so many ways to get latlng when mouse clicked on map. when i use @click="handleClick" its only get mouse event not a value latlng that i want.
i tries using map.on('click', function(e)) but got error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on')"
anyone can help my problem?

```js
  import { computed, ref, onMounted, onUnmounted, watch, reactive } from 'vue'
  import marker from '../../assets/mapMarker.svg'
  import leaflet from 'leaflet'

  let map
  // map = leaflet.map('map').setView([0, 0], 13)
  onMounted(() =>{
    map = leaflet.map('map').setView([0, 0], 13)
    leaflet.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
    {
      maxZoom: 19,
      doubleClickZoom: 'false',
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    }).addTo(map);
    getGeoLocation()
  })
  
  const coords = ref(null)
  const fetchCoords = ref(null)
  const geoMarker = ref(null)

  const initGeoLocation = (lat, lng) => {
    map.setView([lat, lng], 13);
    leaflet.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
    {
      maxZoom: 19,
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    }).addTo(map);
  }

  const plotGeoLocation = (lat, lng) => {
    const customMarker = leaflet.icon({
      iconUrl: marker,
      iconSize: [35,35],
    })
    geoMarker.value = leaflet.marker([lat, lng], { icon: customMarker }).addTo(map)
    map.setView([lat, lng], 10)
  }

  const getGeoLocation = () => {
    fetchCoords.value = true
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setCoords, getLocError)
  }

  const setCoords = (pos) => {
    fetchCoords.value = null
    initGeoLocation(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude)
    const setSessionCoords = {
      lat: pos.coords.latitude,
      lng: pos.coords.longitude,
    }
    sessionStorage.setItem('coords', JSON.stringify(setSessionCoords))

    coords.value = setSessionCoords

    plotGeoLocation(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude)

  } 

  const getLocError = (err) => {
    console.log(err)
  }

  map.on('click', function(e){
  var coord = e.latlng;
  var lat = coord.lat;
  var lng = coord.lng;
  console.log("You clicked the map at latitude: " + lat + " and longitude: " + lng);
  });
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="h-96">
    <div id="map" class="h-full z-[1]">
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: For starters, you shouldn't use map.on outside onMounted. You can clearly see that `let map` is undefined in setup

Comment: @EstusFlask can you write that with a clear example as answer please?

Comment: @helle I posted it for clarity

Answer (score 1):

`map` is undefined and cannot be used until it's assigned on component mount. Any code that depends on it should be evaluated after that, e.g.:

```
  let map;

  onMounted(() =>{
    map = leaflet.map('map').setView([0, 0], 13)
    ...
    map.on('click', ...);
  })
```

Notice that in this snippet `click` event listener is not removed on unmount, this can cause memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Just assign :
let map = undefined
and then use your method to get the latlng example:

```
getLatLng(){map.on('click', function(e){console.log(e.latlng) }}
```

Comment: how would that work? can you give more context please.